# Check if a variable is instance of a type or None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

I have a variable that can be `int` or `None`. If is something else I raise an error.

I have the following code:

```
if not isinstance(id, int) or id is not None:
    raise AttributeError('must be called with a id of type INT or NONE')
```

This is not working, because each condition negates the other and will always raise the error.

Comment: Where's that De Morgan's laws canon when you need it...

Comment: here you go: [deMorgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, you need `and` instead of `or`:

```
if not isinstance(id, (int, )) and id is not None:
    raise AttributeError('must be called with a id of type INT or NONE')
```

Explanation: you're checking to see if the variable is **both** not an `int` **and** not `None`, because as you said, checking either one **or** the other is always `True`

If you prefer to narrow it down to a single check you can do this:

```
if not isinstance(id, (int, type(None))):
    raise AttributeError('must be called with a id of type INT or NONE')
```

Note: you're shadowing the builtin `id` function with that name, try to use a different one to avoid other weird errors

Comment: `not isinstance(id, (int, )) and id is not None`  can also be expressed as `not (id is None or isinstance(id, int))`, which is easier to understand.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that's true, but since the goal is to move to only one `not` condition I find my way of including both within the same `isinstance` more readable

Comment: I didn't mean your second solution wasn't good in this case, just that as more general solution you can transform `not A and not B` into `not (A or B)` (one single negation), which is proven to be easier to understand by an average human brain.

Comment: agreed, that's true